# Wordpress wp_enqueue_style, style version number does not work?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to get my CSS Version number to print out via `wp_enqueue_style`. The Codex suggest what I am doing should work, but instead, my version number ends up in where media should be declared? And Media is omitted?

My function is this…

```
function transition_register_styles(){
  $version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );
  wp_enqueue_style('transition',  get_template_directory_uri(), "styles.css", array(), $version, 'print');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'transition_register_styles');
```

Output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="transition-css" href="https://wp-test/wp-content/themes/transition-starter-theme?ver=5.4.2" type="text/css" media="1.0">theme?ver=5.4.2" type="text/css" media="1.0">
```

What I expected…

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="transition-css" href="https://wp-test/wp-content/themes/transition-starter-theme?ver=1.0" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a "," insteand a "." in the parameters between get_template_directory_uri() and "styles.css"

try

```
 wp_enqueue_style('transition',  get_template_directory_uri() . "styles.css", array(), $version, 'print');
```

Comment: This explains how to fix the problem, which is good. However it would be better if you also explained what was wrong and why this works (i.e. they are not actually separate parameters which is why the `,` causes the problem, etc) so this answer is more helpful to the OP and other people too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'STYLE-NAME', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $theme_version );
```

or

```
$theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'STYLE-NAME', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), $theme_version );
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like it will fix the problem at all. Also, code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to explain what this does differently and how this fixes the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @FluffyKitten, This is WordPress twenty-twenty default theme's code and I have checked it. It is working properly.

Comment: I didn't say your code was wrong, I said it won't fix the OP's problem. If you are giving a few lines of code to fix a problem, it should use the code the gave in the question - you have made no effort to write the code to work for the OP (e.g. using their style nameor print media). This would be ok if you also explained how the code fixed the problem, but you didn't do that either. Inexperienced users could be confused about why there are 2 lines, what the difference is and what they need to do to make this work in their code.